# How to fix the error "There are multiple DataStores active"

Tags: java, android, kotlin, datastore

I have an error in the project. When I use the DataStore on my project then I get an error.
I do not intend to create several datastore for my project. I do want to create a datastore for it but when running the project I get an error

and I found many questions on the StackOverflow.com like

1- [Git push results in "Authentication Failed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659206/git-push-results-in-authentication-failed)

2- [Why there is multiple Datastore is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70091544/why-there-is-multiple-datastore-is-created)

and etc...

but my project error's not resolved

**how to fix that**

this is my code in the *UserPreferences.kt*

```kotlin
    class UserPreferences @Inject constructor(context: Context) {
      //  private val dataStore = context.dataStore
      private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore(name = "userPrefs")
        private val context = context.applicationContext
    
    
    
    
        companion object {
            private val ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY = stringPreferencesKey("accessToken")
            private val REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY = stringPreferencesKey("refreshToken")
        }
    
    
        val getAccessToken: Flow<String>
            get() = context.dataStore.data.map {
                it[ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY]?:""
            }
    
        suspend fun setRefreshToken(value: String) {
            context.dataStore.edit { it[ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY] = value }
        }
    
        val getRefreshToken: Flow<String>
            get() = context.dataStore.data.map {
                it[REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY]?:""
            }
    
        suspend fun setAccessToken(value: String) {
            context.dataStore.edit { it[REFRESH_TOKEN_KEY] = value }
        }
        suspend fun clear() {
            context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
                preferences.clear()
            }
        }
    
    }
```

**Error**:

```
     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.alpha.caller, PID: 11412
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: There are multiple DataStores active for the same file: /data/user/0/com.example/files/datastore/userPrefs.preferences_pb. You should either maintain your DataStore as a singleton or confirm that there is no two DataStore's active on the same file (by confirming that the scope is cancelled).
            at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$file$2.invoke(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:168)
            at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$file$2.invoke(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:163)
            at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
            at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.getFile(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:163)
            at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.readData(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:380)
            at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.readDataOrHandleCorruption(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:359)
            at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.readAndInit(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:322)
            at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.readAndInitOrPropagateAndThrowFailure(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:302)
            at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.handleUpdate(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:281)
            at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.access$handleUpdate(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:76)
            at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$actor$3.invokeSuspend(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:242)
            at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$actor$3.invoke(Unknown Source:8)
            at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$actor$3.invoke(Unknown Source:4)
            at androidx.datastore.core.SimpleActor$offer$2.invokeSuspend(SimpleActor.kt:122)
            at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
            at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

Answer (score 10):

This was throwing me too, but I figured it out (aka, guessed until it worked):

```java
    // Note: This is at the top level of the file, outside of any classes.
    private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("user_preferences")
    
    class UserPreferencesManager(context: Context) {
        private val dataStore = context.dataStore
        // ...
    }
```

This is for a

```
DataStore<Preferences>
```

, but if you need a custom serializer, you can do the following (same parameters as the old method):

```
// Still top level!
private val Context.dataStore by dataStore(
    fileName = "user_preferences",
    serializer = MyCustomSerializer,
)
```

Comment: Yeah outside the class is key, thanks for this! Otherwise I guess the singleton-ensuring property delegate is class-scoped, and even if the class is a singleton in your app's DI graph, when DI gets ripped down and set up again in tests you get a new instance in the same process. At least that's what it looks like is happening.

Comment: That worked. Any idea why it works that way? Does that makes it no longer a SingleProcess Datastore?